# What is the purpose of "analysed" button in Kibana 4?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin, kibana-4

Description:
​I have set up Kibana 4 and also configured an index for analytics. So in the discover page,of Kibana,I can see my index name and the corresponding fields in the index there. To the right side of the fields panel,there is a settings icon. When I click that,four options are shown to me namely analyzed,index,type and Field Name. I know the purpose of index,type and Field Name but Im confused,with what the "analyzed" option stands for. On clicking the drop down under the analyzed section there are options 1. any,2.yes 3.no. Can any body tell what purpose does "analyzed" option have here.

Edit : The screenshots are given in this link
![1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NB0M.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we create an index in elasticsearch,we also have a lot of fields accompanying it. In the "discover" tab,under the "fields" section,we can see each and every field in the selected index. What happens when we set the "analysed" dropdown to "yes" is that the fields which have undergone complete analysis by the elasticsearch analyzers. 
An example for an index named "restaurants" is shown in the fig below. Here the blue box has all the fields which have undergone analysis.
[image]

You can see the number of fields getting reduced as we select the "yes" in the "analysed" dropdown. These are the fields which are analysed. Now on clicking one of those fields,another dropdown comes in with the names and the percentage values of the contents in that particular field. Here we can manipulate the contents of hits by including or excluding that field element by clicking the "+" or "-" magnifying glass(box 3) towards the right of the element(box 2) as shown below.
[image]

Pressing the "+" button(box 1),will show only the results containing that  particular element of that field, from the hits response. You can see the resulting JSON data, by pressing the arrow button just below (box 2) the "_source" as in figure 3.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

An analyzed field in ES, it is a field that is processed into tokens and indexed in that way. You can read more about [analyzers](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) in the ES documentation.

This dropdown is used to get the `analyzed` fields if you select `yes`, the `not_analyzed` if you select `no` and everything if you select `any`.